# VBA fill column conditionally

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel to automate data cleaning. I want to create a column called "Group 1". I have another column First Name and another called Last Name. If the first name and last name is empty fill the Group 1 column with yes.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Note: you don't need VBA. You can achieve that by using formula in column "Group1" `= IF(OR(A2="",B2=""), 1, 0)` See: [MSDN documetation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)

Comment: I am able to do w/o VBA. I need to use via though to be able to automate cleaning hundreds of identical files. Thanks for your input though !

Comment: write in cell C2 : =If(A2&B2="","Yes","no")

Answer (score 0):

These two worked for me...
Hope this helps, you don't need VB6 for this:

```
Sub Macro1()
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1):
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & i) = "" Or Range("B" & i) = "" Then
        Range("C" & i) = "No"
    Else: Range("C" & i) = "Yes"
    End If
    Next
End With
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1):
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=+IF(CONCATENATE(RC[-2]&RC[-1])="""",""Yes"",""No"")"
    Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
End With
End Sub
```